# 2 column form with a save and submit button and am trying to disable the submit button until form is complete

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a 2 column form that I have tried building with both divs and tables that has a save and submit button and I am trying to disable the submit button with javascript until the form is complete. Is it because I have DIVs in the form?

Here is the html:

```
<div style="float:left;  width:450px;">
<form class="form" name="parts" method="post" >

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;">SET PART #</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;">INSTALL DATE</div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">1.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part1"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part1-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">2.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part2"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part2-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">3.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part3"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part3-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">4.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part4"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part4-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">5.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part5"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part5-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">6.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part6"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part6-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">7.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part7"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part7-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">8.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part8"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part8-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">9.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part9"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part9-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">10.</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="text" id="part10"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input type="text" id="part10-install-date"></div>

  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:35px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:187px;"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"></div>
  <div style="float:left; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:7px;  width:192px;"><input class="send" id="register" type="submit" value="Send" disabled="disabled"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); 
    }
});
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the selector "form > input"  means input as a first level child of form.

as you stated its because the inputs are inside of divs and therefor second level children of the form.

try form > div > input or form input instead.

Comment: Your suggestion worked when I tried it in jsfiddle but I cant seem to get it to work on a php page.

Comment: use browser tools to see what the rendered html actually looks like.  Remember js does not care about what generated the html but only what is currently on the page.  I would guess there is other html being inserted when rendering.

Comment: Got it, I was missing the jquery.min.js file in my header. Thanks!